# How to evaluate "Who's on first?" as being equal to "whos on first." in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, text, comparison

I need to evaluate two strings as being equal even if they have minor punctuation differences that would not make them different for the purposes of a Google search.

For example, these pairs would be considered equal (along with any other minor grammatical/spelling mistakes you can think might work in Google):

```
Who's on first?
whos on first.

Where's the beef/problem?
wheres the beef problem
```

Is there a library function in JavaScript that would do this?

Comment: You can just strip the punctuation characters from both strings before comparing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really naive way since it obviously doesn't handle a whole range of issues like misspellings:

```
var a = "some text totest....ok";
var b = "sometext totest ok";

function testRoughEquality(a, b) {
  var ax = a.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "");
  var bx = b.replace(/[^a-z]/gi, "");

  if(ax === bx)
    {
    alert('These strings were roughly the same: "' + a + '" and "' + b + '"');
    }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: Though of course this equates as equal "I helped my uncle Jack off his horse" and "I helped my uncle jack-off his horse" :)

Comment: @Phrogz yes indeed!  I bet heuristic approaches would get that wrong, too, but then I've never written language analyzers.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually not a simple task, to do it right you need to look up [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is to remove characters that don't matter (the apostrophes and punctuation in your example), normalize other characters to word separators (the slash in your example), and downcase the lot.

```
var strs = ["Who's on first?","whos on first."];
for (var i=0,len=strs.length;i<len;++i){
  strs[i] = strs[i].replace(/['?.]/g,'').replace(/[\/]/g,' ').toLowerCase();
}
console.log( strs[0] == strs[1] );
// true
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was only the punctuation and capitalisation issue (like the examples above), a simple solution would be to pass both through a regular expression to remove certain punctuation characters, then convert to lower case and compare.

Something like:

```
function stringCompare(str1, str2)
{
    var test = /[\?\'\/]/g;
    var s1 = str1.replace(test,"").toLowerCase();
    var s2 = str2.replace(test,"").toLowerCase();
    if(str1 === str2) { return true; }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"who's on First?".replace(/[\?' ]/g,'').toLowerCase()
```

Gets you closer, but it's not the best way to do it.

Comment: I like Jonathon's answer better.  Doesn't take into account case though.  You still want to use .toLowerCase()